# Number of points on an affine hypersurface

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I am curious to know the following and I would appreciate any help!

Let $k$ be a finite field of $q$ elements. Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{n+1}_k $ be the
affine hypersurface defined by $f = \sum_{i=0}^n x_i^d$.
Let $R_e = k[t] / (t^{e+1}) $ for some natural number $e$. Denote $X^* = X - \{ 0 \}$.

What is the relation between
$\# X^*(k)$ and $ \# X^*(R_e)$?
(or what is $\# X^*(k) / \# X^*(R_e)$?)